# How to install Vmware tools to Redhat Atomic Host

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat

We are looking at deploying [RHEL Atomic Host](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-atomic-getting-started) on top of ESXi. We need (Open) VMWare Tools on top of the Atomic Host OS to take snapshots and send over heartbeats. Since [yum is not available in the OS](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-atomic-getting-started#install-pkg), what would be the way to go?

Comment: Given the constraints on Atomic Host, I'm not sure if that's possible. Your first move should be to open a case with Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, we did that. Just wondering if anyone has experience and advice on that.

Comment: We ended up giving up on Atomic Host and built our own using kickstart. Mind you that they are using a modified version of docker 1.5 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom Atomic Host Images that include any RPM.

http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/01/08/creating-custom-atomic-trees-images-and-installers-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles over this.
A pkg-add feature has been added to atomic host:

```
rpm-ostree pkg-add open-vm-tools
```

It is broken in current version, but announced to be fixed with next release.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat now ships an `open-vm-tools` container that can be installed as a [system container](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/09/intro-to-system-containers/) to provide the VMWare Tools.

https://access.redhat.com/containers#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/open-vm-tools

There is documentation on using the `open-vm-tools` container as a system container here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/running_system_containers#using_the_open_vm_tools_system_container_image_for_vmware

Answer (score 0):

I believe RHEL has a vmware-friendly Atomic Host with vmwaretools/open-vm-tools installed for subscribers.  But for CentOS you will need to build your own image to add open-vm-tools. Here are steps on how to do so:

https://github.com/imsweb/centos7-atomic-custom